# Dynamically adding content to a dynamically created textarea

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net

I'm encountering a bit of a problem and was wondering if anyone knows what could be the issue.

I have a dynamically created TextArea and I'm trying to set the content of that TextArea dynamically as well from values I'm passing up from a database.  When I attempt to do this via the use of innertext, value or innterHtml the textarea has no content within it.  Does anyone know if there's something obvious I'm missing out?

```
objControl = New HtmlTextArea
Dim txtAreaCtrl As HtmlTextArea = DirectCast(objControl, HtmlTextArea)
Dim rsType As Type = GetType(HtmlTextArea)
txtAreaCtrl.InnerText = datData.Rows(0).Item(dcData.ColumnName)
```

Comment: Share your code as well.

Comment: Just added the code there!

Comment: change **txtAreaCtrl.InnerText = d....** with **txtAreaCtrl.InnerText = txtAreaCtrl.InnerText & d....**

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't appear to work.

Comment: Just like that, it should work. Are you adding the control somewhere? Is the data you are trying to set actually exist? Have you tried putting hardcoded text to test? Do you clear your controls somewhere?

Comment: I've tried hardcoded text as well.  It's odd prior to this I was using a textbox and that worked by simply setting the .text to the database value.  But while the textarea loads up and through debugging I can see the value being set when it loads there's no value.